# How to run a C thread from ruby via swig

Tags: c, ruby, opengl, pthreads, swig

I am, just for fun, trying to make a little game engine with the help of openGL, I want it to be pure C but I'd like to script the games in ruby.
So I've made a sort of proof of concept to know if it was possible, or not. And it seems to be ok but not totally.

Actually, I have a C module wrapped with swig and loaded by a ruby script.
In this C module, I create a thread with pthread_create() containing the glutmainloop().
This loop just loads a mesh draws it and makes it turn at a speed we'll call rot_speed.

Because I don't want my ruby to wait for C mutexes to be unlocked, my ruby runs C functions that creates thread that will change some values for the main loop (so it's completely ASYNC) and then, will die.

here is a portion of the C code :

```
mxfloat_t speed = { 
    .val = 1.0,
    .mx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
};

mxint_t should_exit = { 
    .val = 0,
    .mx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
};


void    engine_launch(void)
{
    pthread_t graphics;
    printf("starting gaphics thread...\n");
    pthread_create(&graphics, NULL, launch_graphics, NULL);
}

void    engine_stop(void)
{
    pthread_t stop_thread;
    printf("starting stop thread");
    pthread_create(&stop_thread, NULL, engine_stop_thread, NULL);
}

void    set_speed(float p)
{
    pthread_t speed_thread;
    printf("starting set speed thread speed= %f\n", p); 
    pthread_create(&speed_thread, NULL, set_speed_thread, &p);
}

void    *launch_graphics(void *p) 
{
    int c = 1;
    char *v = "Ex";

    printf("gaphics thread started\n");
    printf("Initializing Glut...\n");
    glutInitWindowSize(900,600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInit(&c, &v);

    printf("Creating window\n");
    glutCreateWindow("Assim p - Very simple OpenGL sample");
    printf("Assigning callbacks functions\n");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    printf("Loading asset...");
    if(loadasset( "../../test/models-nonbsd/X/dwarf.x")) { 
        printf(" ..failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }   
    printf(" ..loaded\n");

    glClearColor(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,1.f);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);    // Uses default lighting parameters

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

    if(getenv("MODEL_IS_BROKEN"))  
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE);

    glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    printf("Starting main GL loop\n");
    glutMainLoop();
    printf("End of GL loop\n");
    printf("releasing imported objects\n");
    aiReleaseImport(scene);
    printf("End of the graphic thread\n");
    return NULL;

}

void    *engine_stop_thread(void* p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&should_exit.mx);
    should_exit.val = 1;
    printf("should_exit has been set to 1\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&should_exit.mx);
    (void)p;
    return NULL;
}

void    *set_speed_thread(void *p) 
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&speed.mx);
    speed.val = *(float*)p;
    printf("speed has been set to %f\n", *(float*)p);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&speed.mx);
    return NULL;
}
```

mxfloat_t and
mxint_t are just types to handle mutexes.

the functions : 
   engine_launch(),
   engine_stop(), and
   set_speed(f), are the wrapped functions I can use in ruby.

the Idle function is the one that calls glutLeaveMainLoop() if should_exit

now, some ruby code :

```
require "ge"

Ge.engine_launch
sleep 1
Ge.set_speed 32.0 
sleep 1
Ge.set_speed 32.0 
sleep 1
Ge.set_speed 32.0 
sleep 1
Ge.set_speed 32.0 
sleep 1
Ge.engine_stop
sleep 1
```

this code gives me :

```
starting gaphics thread...
gaphics thread started
Initializing Glut...
Creating window
Assigning callbacks functions
Loading asset... ..loaded
Starting main GL loop
starting set speed thread speed= 32.000000
speed has been set to 0.000000
starting set speed thread speed= 32.000000
speed has been set to 0.000000
starting set speed thread speed= 32.000000
speed has been set to 0.000000
starting set speed thread speed= 32.000000
speed has been set to 0.000000
starting stop threadshould exit has been set to 1
```

but if I test in irb :

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'ge'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Ge.engine_launch
starting gaphics thread...
gaphics thread started
Initializing Glut...
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> Creating window
Assigning callbacks functions
Loading asset... ..loaded
Starting main GL loop
Ge.set_speed 32
starting set speed thread speed= 32.000000
speed has been set to 32.000000
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> Ge.set_speed 31
starting set speed thread speed= 31.000000
speed has been set to 31.000000
=> nil
```

(But, irb seems to send some kind of termcap that forces me to reset my terminal)

Does someone know why it's not setting the speed value when running the ruby script?
Are there other possible ways to achieve what I'd want to do?
Thanks for your answers, it will help a lot.